# Where are ASP.NET temporary files stored in Kestrel?

Tags: macos, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

On our dot net core project we are using ViewComponents.

When we change the View referenced by one of our ViewComponents, when "dotnet run watch" is running the end result does not update until we restart dotnet. Creating a new view with the same code which our view component uses, causes it to update and works. This is very frustrating when trying to debug an error only to remember you need to restart dotnet

Can someone please tell me how we can force recompile or ignore certain directories from this cache?

This is happening on .netcoreapp 1.1 on OSX

Answer (score 1):

dotnet-watch keeps an in-memory list of files that it is watching. You can inspect this list by running `dotnet watch --list`.

By default, `dotnet-watch` only restarts the process when Compile and EmbeddedResource items change. This normally only includes *.cs and *.resx files, but may include other files depending on your project.

To exclude a folder, you can set "Watch=false" on these items.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Update="ignored_dir\**\*.cs" Watch="false" />
</ItemGroup>
```

You can explicitly add new filetypes to watch by adding `<Watch>` items to your *.csproj file. Examples:

```
<ItemGroup>
   <Watch Include="*.js" />
   <Watch Include="somefile.txt" />
   <Watch Include="subdir\**\*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Just for clarity's sake, dotnet-watch is independent of Kestrel.

For more details, see https://github.com/aspnet/DotNetTools/tree/1.0.1/src/Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools#msbuild

Comment: do you know if there is a way to get a handle to the temp file?  i don't want to copy the file to my system if kestrel already has.